# Как учесть, угол поворота прямоугольника на плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть прямоугольник и отрезок, необходимо определить факт пересечения отрезком прямоугольника.

```
if ((p1.x < p2.x) && (p1.y>p2.y)) {
    p3.x = p1.x;
    p3.y = p2.y;
    p4.x = p2.x;
    p4.y = p1.y;
    break;
}
cout << "Некорректный ввод." << endl;
```

Проверка координат, на то, что мы действительно ввели диагональ прямоугольника. Исходя из этого необходимо учесть и угол его наклона относительно оси Х, т.к. через две точки можно построить бесконечное кол-во прямоугольников. Нужны идеи реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть прямоугольник и отрезок, необходимо определить факт пересечения
>   отрезком прямоугольника.

Это можно сделать например, пересекая данный отрезок с каждой стороной (или отрезком) прямоугольника - достаточно одного пересечения.

Как пересекать отрезки - классическое решение при помощи векторного произведения.

C++ псевдокод -

```
double cross2d(const vec2& a, const vec2& b) 
{
    return a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x;
}

bool segmentsIntersect(const vec2& p1, const vec2& p2, const vec2& p3, const vec2& p4) 
{
    int v1 = cross2d(
        vec2(p4.x - p3.x, p4.y - p3.y),
        vec2(p1.x - p3.x, p1.y - p3.y)
    );

    int v2 = cross2d(
        vec2(p4.x - p3.x, p4.y - p3.y),
        vec2(p2.x - p3.x, p2.y - p3.y)
    );

    int v3 = cross2d(
        vec2(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y),
        vec2(p4.x - p1.x, p4.y - p1.y)
    );

    int v4 = cross2d(
        vec2(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y),
        vec2(p3.x - p1.x, p3.y - p1.y)
    );

    return v1*v2 < 0 && v3*v4 < 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за пример, но с этим уже справился. Не знаю как учесть угол поворота. С обычным прямоугольником параллельным оси Х все просто.

Comment: @LokenGarvel' угол поворота уже учитывается в этом решении, так как алгоритм пересечения отрезков работает для отрезков с любым углом наклона

Comment: сейчас попробуем. Значит спасибо за подсказку. Вопрос закрыт)